# Simulating queuing in a clinic with three Doctors, with closing time

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to simulate the following process

> Simulation of a queuing problem: a clinic has three doctors. Patients
>   come into the clinic at random, starting at 9 a.m., according to a
>   Poisson process with time parameter 10 minutes: that is, the time
>   after opening at which the first patient appears follows an
>   exponential distribution with expectation 10 minutes and then, after
>   each patient arrives, the waiting time until the next patient is
>   independently exponentially distributed, also with expectation 10
>   minutes. When a patient arrives, he or she waits until a doctor is
>   available. The amount of time spent by each doctor with each patient
>   is a random variable, uniformly distributed between 5 and 20 minutes.
>   The office stops admitting new patients at 4 p.m. and closes when the
>   last patient is through with the doctor.

My attempt so far involves generating the set of patients and then generating the appointment durations, but I am not sure How to move forward from here?

```
t = 0
PATIENT_ARRIVAL_TIMES = []
while t < 420:
     a = expon.rvs(scale=10,loc=0,size=1)
     t = t+a[0]
     PATIENT_ARRIVAL_TIMES.append(t)
NUM_PATIANTS = len(PATIENT_ARRIVAL_TIMES)
APPOINTMENT_DURATIONS = np.random.uniform(5,20,NUM_PATIANTS)
```

I need to now simulate the process, I need to understand what the waiting time for each patient will be, when will the clinic close? (As the last patient may arrive at 3:50 PM and have an appointment 20 minutes long).

Comment: Try (re)searching "queueing". Python has a queue datatype. Find and understand a similar problem to your own then modify that.

Comment: Nice example here... https://realpython.com/simpy-simulating-with-python/

Answer (score 1):

The Python SimPy module can be used for such simulations. This is their example of queueing at a bank: https://pythonhosted.org/SimPy/Tutorials/TheBank.html